# Отнесение "так" к корреляту в предложении

Tags: спп

> Князь Андрей, думавший, что ему было все равно, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так, как взяли Смоленск, внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло.

Можно ли отнести *"так"* к корреляту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Местоименная пара ТАК...КАК (коррелят - союзное слово) характерна для СПП местоименного типа, и коррелят (ТАК) в таких предложениях является обязательным элементом.